# Unable to change status of Redmine Tracker

Tags: redmine

The issue was initially created under the R&D tracker and the status was set to Resolved. Then I changed its Tracker to Task. But The status was only showing "Resolved". Other status options are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got your problem. actually when your task is already resolved you have no permission to change task status from administration side.

a simple hack :

- change your tracker task to another one
- change status to New
- save the issue.
- go to edit issue again
- change tracker to task
- change status whatever you want

it will work :)